# how can mapped function parameters be constrained without being redefined?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to respect the parameters of mapped function values while still constraining them?

In the example below, I want `t2v` to be able to define functions that each individually choose whether they accept only `string`, `number`, or `string | number` (and not anything else, like `Set<string>` or whatever.

```
function CreatePublisher<
  TopicToValue extends { [topic: string]: (message: string | number) => void }
>(t2v: TopicToValue) {
  const implementation = {}; // pretend that this has been implemented
  return implementation as {
    [k in keyof TopicToValue]: (
      value: Parameters<TopicToValue[k]>[0]
    ) => Promise<void>;
  };
}

const publisher = CreatePublisher({
  fooTopic: (v: number) => {}, // Error: Type '(v: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(v: string | number) => void'.
});
```

It doesn't seem like this is possible in TypeScript. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
type Typed<T> = T extends number | string? {[topic: string]: (message: T ) => void } : never;

TopicToValue extends Typed<number|string>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm looking for a way to do it generically. So if I want `message` to be constrained by `type Json = null | boolean | number | string | Array<Json> | { [key: string]: Json }`, I don't want to have to write out every single type of `Json` value the param can be.

Comment: you can build a simple mapped type without manually typing each type -  `type Typed<T> = T extends null | boolean | number | string | Array<Json> | { [key: string]: Json } ? {[topic: string]: (message: T ) => void } : never;`,  `TopicToValue extends Typed<Json>`.

Comment: Doesn't work. `Type '(v: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(message: { [topic: string]: (message: null) => void; } | { [topic: string]: (message: string) => void; } | { [topic: string]: (message: number) => void; } | { [topic: string]: (message: false) => void; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }) => void'.`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QA6DzWQzOIA

Comment: Awesome!! You rule!

I don't understand why `type Typed<T> = T extends number | string? {[topic: string]: (message: T ) => void } : never;` works and `type Typed<T extends number | string> = {[topic: string]: (message: T ) => void };` doesn't... but regardless, I really appreciate it